Running two dryers same circuit, controlled by switch
I have two dryers side by side in my basement, one is for a dog washing business. One is for my clothes. I don't need both running ever at the same time so I currently just unplug and plug in whichever dryer I'm currently using.
Id like to wire another outlet for the dryer, but I don't have room in the panel for another circuit.
Now in theory I should be able to control two outlets on the same circuit with an on off on switch correct?
If so what switch would I need?
Having a hard time finding any 240/480 switches for on off on.

Those are probably 30 Amp circuits

FYI it’s perfectly legal to have multiple 30A receptacles on a 30A circuit. If you’re OK with manually not running both dryers at the same time, that’s fine. An A/B switch is not required by code.

@nobody Sounds like an answer, there, and we ain't supposed to put answers in comments, right? (wink)

Or this? Two dryers on the same circuit

@Triplefault  lol

This sort of thing is common in the electric vehicle world. People will commonly retrofit their house for an EV charger and install a splitter to share the same circuit with their dryer.  Either the charger or the dryer can run at any given time, but not both.
Some of these have manual switches, but newer models are automatic.  One device has priority and will always receive power when it wants, and the other will only be powered when the priority device is off.  Something like that would allow both dryers to multiplex a circuit, and wouldn't require you to re-wire anything.

You should be able to use a 30 amp, double pole, double throw w/ center off similar to the one shown below from leviton.


If the only goal is to ensure they don't run together (rather than full isolation) you don't need a double pole switch.  The single pole aka 3-way version costs a quarter as much and if you plan it right the down dryer's light will still work.

@jay613 Yes, it would work but I'll take full isolation every time.

I like the slogan, but I would not use a switch like this to provide it!  Seriously, if you were servicing OP's dryer would you rely on this switch, or would you turn the breaker off or unplug it?  OTOH ... with a SPDT switch you can empty one dryer with the light on while the other one runs.  And save $45.  That'll pay for a couple of better vent pipes.  :)

@jay613  I wouldn't ever use any toggle switch to disconnect when servicing anything. Single pole switches used to be popular for many 240V appliances: water heaters, sprinkler pumps, spa heaters and pumps, etc. but they have all been replaced with double pole.  Remember Home Depot's  Single pole water heater timer?... big law suit.   A.C. units still use single pole contactors but there it a disconnect usually within arm's reach.  ....  but the $45 would pay for a lot of beers :-)

@jay613 the purpose of the switch isn't to serve as a disconnect. Its purpose is to prevent both dryers from operating at the same time. To prevent nuisance trips because someone tried to run both dryers at the same time... This is what I would do if I was doing a minor fix (major remodel/new construction I would run a separate circuit).

You don't need a switch to control which outlet is off/on per code.
According to NEC 210.23 (C)

A 30-ampere branch circuit shall be permitted to supply fixed lighting units with heavy-duty lampholders in other than a dwelling unit(s) or utilization equipment in any occupancy. The rating of any one cord-and-plug-connected utilization equipment shall not exceed 80 percent of the branch-circuit ampere rating.

But I think it is a really smart idea. And will save a lot of trips to the breaker box because someone tried to use both dryers at once.
